# FOSRestBundle: PATCH methods not working (501 - Not implemented)

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm using FOSUserBundle (the same problem on 0.12.0 and current dev-master) with Symfony 2.3.
I have problem with PATCH methods.

Simple example:

```
public function patchAction($slug)
{
    [...]
    return $view;
}
```

I see proper route was generated in php app/console router:debug:

```
api_patch_user PATCH ANY ANY /api/users/{slug}.{_format}
```

But when I am making request, I'm getting:

```
501 - Not implemented
```

When I change only method name to i.e. DELETE everything is working. So the problem is only with PATCH type requests.

Comment: What http server are you using ?

Comment: how are you trying to send the PATCH request?

Comment: I'm using lighttp on Ubuntu running on Virtualbox. Really can it change something? I'm sending PATCH request through POSTMAN (chrome extension).

Comment: Give us more information, your class config + an example url you want to call

Comment: How did you solve this? I have the same problem in my test environment, but on production its working. And they are basically on the same infrastructure.